# Kloeden–Platen–Schurz algorithm for SDE

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-calculus

`RandomFunction`'s `Method` setting includes `"Kloeden–Platen–Schurz"` as a possibility. Which is supposed to be order 3/2.

I cannot find a reference to that name of an algorithm anywhere. Is this
*The order 1.5 Strong Taylor Scheme* as referenced in (a very good btw) book *P. Kloeden E. Platen Numerical Solutions of Stochastic Differential Equations* chapter 10.4?

If so, how are the higher stochastic integrals approximated? In this book there is a series expansion presented with an expansion parameter `p` which they choose by trial and error (?)

I'm unable to reproduce the results that Mathematica produces with a code I've wrote from scratch.

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/263878850_The_numerical_solution_of_nonlinear_stochastic_dynamical_systems_A_brief_introduction All three authors on this one. Possible misspellings must be making it harder to find Shur(t)z and Klo(e)den

Comment: @flinty Fixed multiple typos in the question. Sorry about that.

Comment: @flinty Checked out this article and order 1.5 algorithm is not in it :<